# How to run a 3 different batch file in a onego?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, windows-server-2008-r2

I have a three batch file like a.bat,b.bat and c.bat. Now I wanted to execute the all these batch file in a onego but my point is they will execute in order. When 1st complete then 2nd start and when 2nd complete then 3rd start.I used CALL and START and && but it did't work for me.

Comment: Answer can be found in [so] question [Running windows batch file commands asynchronously](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1449188)

Comment: Actually i don't have 3 different .exe. I have to run 3 diff. .bat file in a sequence?

Comment: The answer is the same. You can replace prog.exe with prog.bat or prog.cmd